# Next.js Next/Image Not rendering in production mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

```
  // Image component
import NextImage from 'next/image'

const Image = ({ ...rest }) => <NextImage {...rest} />

export default Image

// calling image

import Image from '@/components/common/Image'

import DeviantImg from './../public/static/images/Deviant_logo_Lg_Red.svg' 

const ComponentName = () = {
    .....   
     <Image alt="Deviant" src={DeviantImg} className="w-full object-contain object-center " />
    ....

}
```

**In development mode (next dev) it was working fine . When running for production mode(next build && next start ) then it was not worked.**

In development mode see below code from inspect element:

```
<img alt="Deviant" src="/_next/static/media/Deviant_logo_Lg_Red.9413135e.svg" decoding="async" data-nimg="intrinsic" class="w-full object-contain object-center " style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;border:none;margin:auto;display:block;width:0;height:0;min-width:100%;max-width:100%;min-height:100%;max-height:100%" srcset="/_next/static/media/Deviant_logo_Lg_Red.9413135e.svg 1x, /_next/static/media/Deviant_logo_Lg_Red.9413135e.svg 2x">
```

In production mode see below code from inspect element(Which is not displayed image):

```
<img alt="Deviant" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" decoding="async" data-nimg="intrinsic" class="w-full object-contain object-center " style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;border:none;margin:auto;display:block;width:0;height:0;min-width:100%;max-width:100%;min-height:100%;max-height:100%">``
```

**Do you have any idea for that situation?**